# Avoid using DynamicInvoke() from a Dictionary<Type, Delegate>

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I have a sort of message broker class that maps incoming message types to handler methods at runtime. It is important for me to maintain strongly typed messages in the handlers. It works by finding all classes that inherit from `IMessage` and creating a `Delegate` to invoke any method that has a `Handles(TMessage)` attribute on it, where `TMessage` matches the incoming `IMessage` underlying `Type`.

So a "handler" looks like this:

```
[Handles(typeof(TestMessage))]
public void HandleTestMessage(objectsender, TestMessage request)
{
    var response = new TestResponse() { TestInt = request.TestInt };

    msgService.Send(sender, response);
}
```

Again, I'd really like to avoid having an `IMessage` in the method signature, it's important to me to not have to cast the `IMessage` in the method body.

The broker class uses the following method to discover and register the handlers:

```
/// <summary>
/// Subscribes all methods with the <see cref="HandlesAttribute"/> to the given <see cref="IMessage"/> <see cref="Type"/>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="target">The object to inspect</param>
public void SubscribeAll(object target)
{
    var targetType = target.GetType();

    // Get all private and public methods.
    var methods = targetType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (var method in methods)
    {
        // If this method doesn't have the Handles attribute then ignore it.
        var handlesAttributes = (HandlesAttribute[])method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HandlesAttribute), false);
        if (handlesAttributes.Length != 1)
            continue;

        // The method must have only 2 arguments.
        var parameters = method.GetParameters();
        if (parameters.Length != 2)
        {
            log.LogDebug(string.Format("Method {0} has too many arguments", method.Name));
            continue;
        }

        // The second argument must be derived from IMessage.
        if (!typeof(IMessage).IsAssignableFrom(parameters[1].ParameterType))
        {
            log.LogDebug(string.Format("Method {0} does not have an IMessage as it's second argument", method.Name));
            continue;
        }

        Type genericDelegate; 

        if(method.ReturnType == typeof(void))
        {
            genericDelegate = typeof(Action<,>).MakeGenericType(parameters[0].ParameterType, handlesAttributes[0].MessageType);
        }
        else
        {
            genericDelegate = typeof(Func<,,>).MakeGenericType(parameters[0].ParameterType, handlesAttributes[0].MessageType, method.ReturnType);
        }

        var handler = method.CreateDelegate(genericDelegate, target);

        // Success, so register!
        Subscribe(
            handlesAttributes[0].MessageType,
            handler);
    }
}
```

and finally when a message is received, it uses this method to invoke (`DynamicInvoke`) the handler:

```
/// <summary>
/// Passes a given <see cref="IMessage"/> and optional sender to any <see cref="Handler"/>s accepting the message's underlying type 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="message">The <see cref="IMessage"/> to send</param>
/// <param name="sender">The original sender of the message</param>
private void HandleMessage(IMessage message, object sender = null)
{
    var messageType = message.GetType();
    if (messageHandlers.TryGetValue(messageType, out List<Delegate> handlers))
    {
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
        {
            handler.DynamicInvoke(new object[] { sender, message });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        log.LogError(string.Format("No handler found for message of type {0}", messageType.FullName));
        throw new NoHandlersException();
    }
}
```

I thought I was being smart when I converted the `MethodInfo`s into `Delegate`s (`Action<,>` or `Func<,,>`) but I neglected to check the implications of using `DynamicInvoke` over `Invoke`. It turns out `DynamicInvoke` incurs a comparatively large amount of overhead. So my question is, how can I treat the handler `Delegate`s as the *actual* `Delegate`s that they are (again, Action<,> or Func<,,>)

As you can see, in `HandleMessage`, I *do* know the underlying type of `message`, and sender is always an object. Basically, I need to do something like:

`((Action<object, typeof(message)>)handler).Invoke(sender, message);`

Obviously that's impossible, but it illustrates what I am trying to accomplish clearly (I think).

I tried creating a sort of in-between generic method:

```
public void InvokeHandler<TMessage>(Action<object, TMessage> handler, TMessage message, object sender = null)
```

But I just run into contravariance problems down the line when trying to invoke this method.

Comment: You have mismatched parens and/or angle brackets in this code (or my eyes are going): ((Action<object, typeof(message))handler).Invoke(sender, message);  Can you try typing it again?

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes you were right. I fixed it.

Comment: Did you fix the code above, or did you fix your issue?

Comment: If you have MethodInfos, Invoking through them directly is somewhat slower than calling through a Delegate (if I remember correctly, I looked into this 10+ years ago), but still pretty fast; certainly faster than DynamicInvoke.  You can fabricate an Action<object, typeof(message)> object through Reflection and then Invoke it (via Reflection), but (guessing) it's likely no faster than DynamicInvoke.  I build worker types that do stuff with MethodInfos semi-regularly (though I've stopped checking them for speed).